# Using a while loop to lead up to a number

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to try and go from 0 to a number inputted by the user. For example if the user puts 6 i want the loop to go from 1 all the way to 6. I have a while loop that goes from the inputted down to 1 but how would i go up to the number inputted.

```
System.out.print("\nEnter a positive integer:");
m = in.nextInt();
sum = m*1.609;
if(m<0) {System.out.println("Please input a positive integer");}

while (m>= 1)
{
    System.out.println(m);
    m = m -1;
}



Enter a positive integer:10
10.0
9.0
8.0
7.0
6.0
5.0
4.0
3.0
2.0
1.0
```

Comment: This code is for converting Miles into kilometers thats why you see all of those weird numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do this, but based on your code:

```
int i=1;
while (i<=m)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    i++;
}
```

Using a for loop is easier:

```
for(int i=1; i <= m; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: what do you think would the best way to do it?

Comment: @DanielAvila I've added an easier approach

Answer (score 2):

```
     float x = 1;
     while (x <= m)
     {
         System.out.println(x);
         x = x +1;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the condition and increment your counter instead of decrementing it :

```
int i = 1 ;
while (i <= m)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    i = i+1;
}
```

it would be much easier to use for loops in such cases :

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= m ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```